# How to call names from sub-packages from a python script running in the root directory?

Tags: python, module, package, python-import

I have the following directory structure for my project

```
project_Rosa

  Rosa
      __init__.py
    
      filehandle
          __init__.py
          fmain.py
    
      punnet
          __init__.py
          pmain.py
    
      sequences
          __init__.py
          smain.py
        
  current_code.py
```

Rosa is the main package I am developing and I am testing the imports from `current_code.py`. All the `__init__.py`s are empty right now. `fmain.py` module has a function `string_fasta()`. The problem is I can directly import it in `current_code.py` with

```
import Rosa.filehandle.fmain as f
function = f.string_fasta
```

or by

```
import Rosa.filehandle.fmain.string_fasta as function
```

but when I write this

```
import Rosa.filehandle as R
a = R.fmain.string_fasta
```

I get an error

```
module 'Rosa.filehandle' has no attribute 'fmain'
```

Please address what is wrong here, and how to call names from modules shallower or deeper than the current script inside it ?

Comment: because `R` references the `__init__.py` file so doing `R.anything` will look for names in the `__init__.py` file, anyways I feel like the contents of the `...main.py` files should be in the `__init__` files, at least as an import from `...main.py` file, because the `__init__.py` is kinda the main file there

Comment: By `import Rosa.filehandle as R` you imported the `Rosa/filehandle/__init__.py`. If `__init__.py` is empty the interpreter will have no idea where `fmain` is or what is in it.

Comment: Okay, so many package tutorials say it can be empty which is so confusing, so what I do is import fmain.py in __init__.py of filehandle ?

Comment: @AdityaPrakash yes, a simple `import fmain` in the `filehandle/__init__.py` file will allow you to use `R.fmain` in the last example

Comment: I added import fmain, still getting an error ; No module named 'fmain'